# JNDI lookup fails (Spring, JBoss)

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jboss, jndi

I have a problem with initializing the application. JNDI lookup is not fully initialized because of a circular reference which is, I think, not there.

Part of `applicationContext.xml` where the problem is:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="txm" jndi-name="java:/TransactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg  type="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" ref="txm" />
    <property name="autodetectUserTransaction" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="60" />
</bean>
```

Error messages:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning eagerly cached instance of singleton bean 'txm' that is not fully initialized yet - a consequence of a circular reference

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txm': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(CamelBeanPostProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `constructor-arg`, just use the `transactionManagerName` property.

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Because there's another problem. I have to use the `txm` more than once and it's not the best solution to do a new lookup every time. But if I use `<property name="transactionManager" ref="txm" />` I get the same error as before. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean you have to use txm more than once? Why aren't you using your transactionManager directly? I mean your bean named transactionManager, of type JtaTransactionManager.

Comment: I have a JmsConnectionFactory which needs the `javax.transaction.TransactionManager` too.

Comment: You can use transactionManager for that? and you still will have only one lookup.

Comment: I can't use the `txManager` bean - `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` can't be used instead of the `javax.transaction.TransactionManager`. I need the `txm` in both places. If I use the `transactionManagerName` property separately for both of them (transactionManager and jmsConnectionFacotry), then it works, but the lookup is done twice.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Still think that two lookups is not the end of the world but it's your decision. Regarding the original question, why it doesn't work with 'ref' i unfortunately don't know the answer.

Comment: I would expect that Spring loads the beans one at a time - so the lookup is done first and until it is finished no bean is created. After that it continues and constructor-args don't have null object anymore. In fact the lookup starts, the next bean right after that and because the lookup hasn't been finished yet the exception occurs.

Comment: Yes i would expect something like that as well. Two tips: a) dl Spring source and try to debug, b) try the springsource forum, usually helpful guys there.

Comment: Ok one more tip: <property name="transactionManager"><ref bean="tmx"/></property>?